# Comparing two arrays and finding difference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, basically i have two arrays like this

```
   const firstArray = [
     {
        subId:40,
        value:280,
        label:'something'
     
     },
{
        subId:42,
        value:280,
        label:'something different'
     
     }
    ]
```

and another array containing videos

```
const secondary = [
{
    chapId: 280,
    label:'any video',
    
},
{
    chapId: 280,
    label:'another video',      
},
{
    chapId: 282,
    label:'another video',      
}
]
```

now i want to return all the result in the secondary array which matches in the firstArray
firstArray.value === secondary.chapId.

which will result like this:

```
 const secondary = [
    {
        chapId: 280,
        label:'any video',
        
    },
    {
        chapId: 280,
        label:'another video',      
    },
    
    ]
```

i tried it using reduce but i am not getting the exact value

I would like to use the resultant array in a dropdown list
for a react component.

Comment: So what are you going to get when satisfies the condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it.

```js
const firstArray = [
  {
 subId:40,
 value:280,
 label:'something'
  
  },
{
 subId:42,
 value:280,
 label:'something different'
  
  }
 ]

const secondary = [
  {
  chapId: 280,
  label:'any video',
  
  },
  {
  chapId: 280,
  label:'another video',      
  },
  {
  chapId: 282,
  label:'another video',      
  }
  ]

let ret = secondary.filter((x) => firstArray.find((y) => x.chapId === y.value));
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Yes it worked absolutely fine.
I really want to practice this chaining while working with arrays.
Do you have any tips for that.

Hugely appreciated mate.Thankss

Comment: Go through all the array functions in JS. You can practice it from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array